# Ngrok / Laravel5 / Homestead - 500 Internal Server Error on Post /Login

Tags: laravel, homestead, ngrok

[**NGROK - 500 Internal Server Error on POST /Login**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy5jj.png)

As seen on the picture, Ngrok works great, everything shows up. However, when doing POST Requests like login, I get a 500 - Internal Server Error. Why is that and how to fix this? Does it has to do with Laravel's CSRF protection (using v5.3)? Thanks in advance!

... looks like the error is in the following, as it returns:

VM61 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 POST http://xxx.ngrok.io/login 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
send @ VM61 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax @ VM61 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ VM62 app.js:195
dispatch @ VM61 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ VM61 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
```

app.js looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
   headers: {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
     'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
   },
   url:'/login',
   type:'POST',
   data:formData,
})
```

Might be of any help. Thanks!

Comment: php artisan make:auth  run this command and try again.

Comment: Already done. Login exists, but POST request doesn't work on the FORWARDING Ngrok address.
It works however on localhost.

Comment: Might be a CORS issue ... check for that

Comment: ok, added "'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'" to the header in ajax and deactivated the "VerifyCsrfToken::classes" in the routes middleware groups in app\Http\Kernel. 
Result: No 500 internal server errors anymore, the login_request works, but still no login-success -> site reloads without logging in user.